# selecting a column with jquery-ui selectable

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a table that represents a physical 12x8 grid. Each `<td>` contains the text name (A1-H12) of the grid co-ordinate. I've added the jquery-ui *[selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/)* interaction to the table.  I want users to be able to select an arbitrary set of grid co-ordinates. As well as selecting `<td>`s I'd like the user to be able to select entire rows and/or columns by clicking on the row or column `<th>`.  Selection by `<th>` is causing me some difficulty:

1. How do I determine which `<td>`s are in the same column (or row) as the selected `<th>`?
2. Which selectable event should I use to move the selection from a `th` to the correct set of `<td>`s? [stop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-stop), [selected](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selected) or [selecting](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#event-selecting)?

My jquery (which only allows me to look at the selected objects since I'm very unsure of how to do things):

```
$(function(){
 $('#selectable').selectable({
  filter:'td,th',
     selected: function(event, ui){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ui);
       var s=$(this).find('.ui-selected');
    console.log(s); 
      }
 })

});
```

The table looks like this:

```
<table id='selectable'>
  <tr>
     <th>&nbsp;</th><!-- empty cell over row labels-->
     <th class='colhead'>1</th>
...
     <th class='colhead'>12</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th class='rowhead'>A</th>
     <td>A1</td>
...
     <td>A12</td>
  </tr>
...
  <tr>
     <th class='rowhead'>H</th>
     <td>H1</td>
...
     <td>H12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error, this is what I figured out. The rowhead selection adds the class to the `<td>` and undoes the selection of the `<th>`'s.  The colhead selection does the same for the columns, but is a bit more complex since you have to get the column index.

I believe these could be more efficient, but I don't know how.  Suggestions are welcome.

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectable').selectable({
        filter:'td,th',
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $('#selectable th.ui-selected.rowhead').siblings('td').addClass('ui-selected').end().removeClass('ui-selected');
            $('#selectable th.ui-selected.colhead').each(function(i){
                col= $(this).parent().children().index($(this)) +1;
                console.log(col)
                $(this).closest('tr').siblings().children('td:nth-child('+col+')').addClass('ui-selected');
                $(this).removeClass('ui-selected');
            });
        }
    })
});
```